# Log info into the default log file of the server

Tags: java, logging, jboss, tomcat8

My Dev machine has JBoss while production server is running tomcat8 on AWS.

How do I setup `Log (java.util.loggin)` to log into default log file in the default directory, for instance following are the default paths for log files for each server. (no 3rd party loggers please)

> /log/tomcat8/catalina
>
> jboss-4.0.4/server/some_server_conf/log/

In some [code examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0_Man88Z3Q) I've seen, a `FileHandler("file.log")` is provided but then this log exists locally within the project folder and is not accessible from outside in a production environment. I want the application to be part of the root logging system that appends the log info into default directories and into default files.

Lateral Thinking: Please advise if there's a totally different strategy for production servers.

Part of the reason is that it's easier to see the log files right from AWS by requesting last 100 lines and I'd like to append some additional meaningful information there regarding my application as it runs.

```
public class Service {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myproject");

    public Service() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "abc");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to simply [install](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) a [`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) on the root logger of your `myproject`.  That would direct all of your project output to the `tomcat8-stderr.YYYY-MM-DD.log`.

Otherwise you can create a [`ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and install a custom handler on the root logger of your project which formats and logs to the [`ServletContext.log` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#log-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-).